# Display content on Single page

Tags: theme-development, pages, templates

I am building a single page theme, And I am having a problem with `get_post_meta()`

#### The Problem

This code bellow does not work, and I cannot see anything on the website as it's blank. Here is my `index.php`.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
   global $query_string, $post;

   query_posts($query_string . "post_type=page&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=9");
   if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
   $home        = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'home', true);
   $about       = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'about', true);
   $contact     = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'contact', true);
   $services    = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'services', true);
?>

<?php if ( $home ) : ?>
    <div id="home" class="borderline">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( $about ) : ?>
<section class="about-us" id="about-us">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The code above does not display anything.

#### Question

- How can I display my content using the code above?
- Guidance on developing single page themes, going forward?
- What page template hierarchy should I put my code?

### My Pages look like this

[image: Wp Pages]

Thank you in advance.

'Ace'

Comment: you are missing the '&' just before 'post_type'; https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/#preserving-existing-query-parameters - also, why are you not using a custom query based on `WP_Query()` ? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mind showing an example?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have generated metafields called 'home', 'about', 'contact' and 'services' in `functions.php` using [`add_post_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_post_meta/) your calls to `get_post_meta` will always return false. So if you test if they are true later on, the answer is 'no' and nothing will be displayed.